# How to analyze firmware time in systemd-analyze?

Tags: systemd, boot, uefi, firmware

Running `systemd-analyze` on my computer gives me `Startup finished in 15.862s (firmware) + 3.356s (loader) + 1.391s (kernel) + 5.199s (userspace) = 25.810s`. The time for firmware is taking longer than I expected, given that it is much shorter on my other computer and Fast Boot is already enabled in my system BIOS interface.

How would I diagnose what part of firmware is making it take this much time? I'm looking for something like `systemd-analyze blame` (used for userspace) or the ability to access time-stamped firmware logs.

Comment: Please check if `showsel` can help https://linux.die.net/man/8/showsel and have a look at `ipmiutil` https://linux.die.net/man/8/ipmiutil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect time-stamped boot logs at the level of individual firmware events only on serious server-grade hardware. But on those, the self-tests tend to be more involved and may take several minutes. With consumer-grade hardware, that level of firmware diagnostics is almost unheard of in my experience.

Some advice on diagnosing what is taking the time, in the order of increasing effort/resources required:

- Look at the display while the firmware phase of the boot process is running. If the system is showing just the manufacturer's logo, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> may switch it to a more informative display. Or you might need to disable the boot logo in BIOS settings. You might see some messages on the screen, referring to different parts of the firmware boot process. For example, network cards, hardware RAID controllers and similar may show their own boot messages, and potentially take a significant time in their own initialization. In most cases, this initialization is only to enable the possibility of booting from that device. If you know you don't need to boot from a network, or from an extra disk/RAID controller, look for ways to disable them. There might be a BIOS setting, or those components might have their own mini-BIOS-setting screen with a key combination to access them displayed at boot time. Or you might need a specific configuration utility program to "disable the BIOS extension / UEFI driver" of a particular component.
- If you have an upmarket desktop, its motherboard might have a two-digit LED display for POST codes. If not, the POST codes could be displayed by [a small diagnostic card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_card) (older systems) or a 
  [USB diagnostic device](https://www.coreboot.org/EHCI_Debug_Port) (modern systems with the "USB Debug Port" functionality). You'll also need to get a list of POST codes applicable to your system: check the system/motherboard manual or the system/motherboard/BIOS vendor's support webpages. Then it's a matter of monitoring the codes as they are displayed during boot, and checking what the codes that are displayed the longest time actually mean: is there any relevant BIOS settings that might shorten or entirely skip that particular phase?
- If you can get the OEM customization utilities for your system's BIOS, you might be able to change some settings that are not available to ordinary mortals. This requires understanding what you're doing, and is well into BIOS modding territory.
- If your hardware is compatible with [coreboot](https://www.coreboot.org/), you might entirely replace your normal BIOS with Coreboot firmware, which can be more customizable and often boots faster. This is a big and not always easily reversible step, that runs the risk of bricking your hardware if you get it wrong: perform careful research before deciding to do this.